# Freebsd11-2: zpool import not surviving reboot

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I have a FreeBSD 11.2-RELEASE install on a SSD and a zpool mirror named `tank` consisting of 2 hard drives.

There is no problem importing it manually:
`zpool import -R /mnt tank`

then `zfs get all tank` shows:

`[root@x9 ~]# zfs get all tank
NAME  PROPERTY              VALUE                  SOURCE
tank  type                  filesystem             -
tank  creation              Wed Oct  3 22:36 2018  -
tank  used                  41.9G                  -
tank  available             1.71T                  -
tank  referenced            66.2M                  -
tank  compressratio         1.00x                  -
tank  mounted               yes                    -
tank  quota                 none                   default
tank  reservation           none                   default
tank  recordsize            128K                   default
tank  mountpoint            /mnt/tank              default`

But the zpool import never survives a reboot.

An helping user suggested that the file `/boot/zfs/zpool.cache` not being updated could be the culprit, so I deleted it, re-imported the zpool and rebooted.

This didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-R` option to `zpool import` sets a temporary prefix to all the mountpoints and does not update the cachefile. See the [zpool(8) manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=zpool) for details.

If you want the datasets of the second pool to be mounted at boot, the system cachefile (at `/boot/zfs/zpool.cache`) needs to be updated.

If you want to update the cachefile you will need to execute `zpool import` without the `-R` option. The manual also mentions specifying the cachefile explicitly (but I have not tested that option).

Assuming that you need to set the mountpoint of the second pool to `/mnt/tank`, you should perform this step before the final import of the pool.

For example:

```
zpool import -R /mnt tank
zfs set mountpoint=/mnt/tank tank
zpool export tank
zpool import tank
```

Comment: I was missing the `zfs set mountpoint=/mnt/tank tank` part. Thank you very much. The zpool now works as expected.